# Python printing a object

Tags: python-3.x

In the below code I need to print the contactlist object..How do I do that?

```
# Test.py
class ContactList(list):
    def search(self, name):
        '''Return all contacts that contain the search value
        in their name.'''
        matching_contacts = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contacts.append(contact)
        return matching_contacts


class Contact:
    all_contacts = ContactList()

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.all_contacts.append(self)
```

I have created 2 object of Contact but want to see all the elements in the all_contacts list..

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
print(Contact.all_contacts)
```

or:

```
for c in Contact.all_contacts:
    print("Look, a contact:", c)
```

To control how the Contact prints, you need to define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method on the Contact class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<Contact: %r %r>" % (self.name, self.email)
```

or, however you want to represent the Contact.

Comment: THis is how it looks...>>> for c in c1.all_contacts:
...     print(c)
...
<__main__.Contact instance at 0x00B56AA8>

Comment: @user1050619: Yes, that is output by the default `__repr__` method for your object.  You want to override the default `__repr__` method with a new one that prints how you want.